# how to replace some text in input value to href?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have input:

```
 html
<input ng-model="inputValue">
```

and scope:

```
 $scope.inputValue = " I want to replace THIS* to some href(make a hyperlink e.g. 'https://www.google.com')"
```

when I render Input and ng-model to it...I want somehow to show current text as link inside Input container.
So I need to make "THIS" word as hyperlink in input field.
[image]

Is that possible???
Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Please share the sample input and expected output.

Comment: you want to have a hyperlink inside a text input field? how exactly?

Comment: so regular expression??? template literals? Your question is unclear how it is supposed to happen so hard to give an answer.

Comment: yes.I do. but not sure if is't realy possible:) Updated with img

Comment: An input is made for the user to type something, an interaction for you to get some text, why would you want to place a link inside it? when user submits the input, what do you want to get? why not simply put a link aside the input?

Comment: You **cannot** have links inside input fields. You should consider separating it by adding: `<a ng-href={{inputValue}}>Link</a>`

Comment: I think I will use http://textangular.com/

Comment: @Serhiy I think you are looking for a **WYSIWYG text editor**, such as the one you found or CKEditor and similar ones. They use `<textarea>` and not `<input>` fields

Comment: yes yes. thanks Aleksey!!!